# react hook forms with react google autocomplete not showing selected value on first select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form, react-autocomplete, react-google-autocomplete

using react hooks form with react google autocomplete. Problem is on first selection, the react google autocomplete does not show the selected value, but just what the user types. Only if you select it the second time then it will say what you select. Subsequent selects are fine.

For example, user types in `Disneyland` and you select `Disneyland Resort, Disneyland Drive, Anaheim, CA, USA` from the autocomplete list, it still says `Disneyland`, but if you choose `Disneyland Resort, Disneyland Drive, Anaheim, CA, USA` again, it will now say that. anyone have any idea why this is happening and how to fix to get it to show the first time on select?

here is the code

```
import AutoComplete from "react-google-autocomplete";
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";

const {
  register,
  handleSubmit,
  control,
  formState: { touchedFields, errors },
  reset,
  watch,
} = useForm();

<Controller
  name="name"
  control={control}
  render={({ field, fieldState }) => (
    <AutoComplete
      apiKey={some_api_key}
      options={{
        types: ["establishment"],
        fields: ["name"],
      }}
      {...field}
    />
  )}
/>;
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
import AutoComplete from "react-google-autocomplete";
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";

const { ..., control } = useForm();

<Controller
  control={control}
  name="location"
  render={({ field: { onChange } }) => (
    <AutoComplete
       apiKey={GOOGLE_API_KEY}
       onPlaceSelected={(place) => onChange(place.formatted_address)}
     />
   )}
  />
/>;
```

`onChange` sends the value to the form's registry.

Taken directly from the docs [here](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller/controller).

Using react-hook-form: v 7.39.5

react-google-autocomplete: v 2.7.0